# sudo prevent switches/arguments on command

Tags: sudo

Is it possible to allow a user to run a command using sudo, but prevent them from adding any arguments to the command?

For example, if I want a user to be able to run:

```
/sbin/mii-tool
```

but not:

```
/sbin/mii-tool -r
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Fine Manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) sez:

> you can specify "" to indicate that the command may only be run **without** command line arguments.

So in your case, you'd probably do something like:

```
ALL ALL=(root) /sbin/mii-tool ""
```

(Probably throwing in a `NOPASSWD:` for convenience)

Comment: Nice catch, had a hard time finding that myself

Comment: `man sudoers`, first result for 'argument'.  Rocket science it ain't.